# Flutter Charts View

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to develop a bar graph shown in the below image
I could not find any packages that can help me achieve it.
I want the graph to start from the center and go x axis and -x axis .
can anyone give me some idea
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check this is the [link](https://fluttergems.dev/plots-visualization/).
This link to check different kinds of packages and create awesome charts